# Can React selectors return jsx?

Tags: reactjs

When I write my React applications I keep all state, props calculations in separate functions. I call them selectors, though I'm not sure if those are selectors. By definition, selectors are functions which return subsets of state or props. I have several questions concerning this issue:

1) Can selectors return jsx objects?

For example, I would like to populate `<Item />` into another component

```js
selectorItem = (state, props) => {
    const { items } = props;

    const ItemsJSX = items.map((item) => {
        return (
            <Item
                item={item}
                key={item.id}
            />
        )
    });

    return {
        items: ItemsJSX
    }
}

class Page extends Component {

render() {
        return (
            <List 
                {...selectorItem(this.state, this.props)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Is this a valid selector?
If not, how can I populate JSX into another component using selectors?

2) Should I write selector per component (selector returns object with multiple props) or per prop (separate selector per prop)?

```js
selectorItemsComments = (state, props) => {
    const { items } = props;
    const { comments } = props;

    const ItemsJSX = items.map((item) => {
        return (
            <Item
                item={item}
                key={item.id}
            />
        )
    });

    const CommentsJSX = comments.map((comment) => {
        <Comment
            comment={comment}
            key={comment.id}
        />
    });

    return {
        items: ItemsJSX,
        comment: CommentsJSX
    }
}
```

versus

```js
selectorItems = (state, props) => {
    const { items } = props;

    const ItemsJSX = items.map((item) => {
        return (
            <Item
                item={item}
                key={item.id}
            />
        )
    });

    return {
        items: ItemsJSX
    }
}

selectorComments = (state, props) => {
    const { comments } = props;
    const CommentsJSX = comments.map((comment) => {

        return (
            <Comment
                comment={comment}
                key={comment.id}
            />
        )
    });

    return {
        comment: CommentsJSX
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Technically, the thing you are calling "selectors" are just components.

Answer (score 3):

These are not `selectors` the are just `functions` returning components

**TL;DR**
The short answer is yes you can return `Components` from functions.

**Full Answer**
In your simpler first example you should just return the component array from your `selectorItem` (I have renamed this to `renderItems`) function:

```js
const renderItems = (items) => items.map((item) => 
  <Item
    item={item}
    key={item.id}
  />          
);

const renderComments = (comments) => comments.map((comment) => 
  <Comment
    item={comment}
    key={comment.id}
  />          
);

class Page extends Component {  
  render() {
    const {items, comments} = this.props;
    return (
      <List>
        {renderItems(items)}
        {renderComments(comments)}
      </List>
    );
  }
}
```

I would recommend converting `renderItems` to a `Component` and then you could do something like:

```js
<List>
  <Items items={items} />
  <Comments comments={comments} />
</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If I understand correctly, your selector is still a React component. This pattern is called "Smart vs Dumb" component, or [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).
2. Is [HOCs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) (Higher Order Component) what you want ?